# MySQL – replace part of strings ending with '/'

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, phpmyadmin

I have very little experience with SQL. I am stuck with seemingly very simple task – I've copied a row with contract numbers, which includes a two-digit year number (**EG 1/14, 31/15, 221/17**) into a new "year" row.

Now I need to replace the digits left from the forward slash and slash itself with '20' string to get pretty full year (**EG 2014, 2015, 2017**). The row is VARCHAR.

I was trying this:

```
UPDATE contracts SET year = REPLACE(year, '%/', '20')
```

or this:

```
UPDATE contracts SET year = REPLACE(year, '*/', '20')
```

Which did not throw error, but did not update anything (0 rows affected…).

I was trying even regexp, but this throws error, so obviously the syntax must be wrong:

```
UPDATE contracts SET year = REPLACE(year, '.+/\', '20')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not support regular expressions with `replace()`.  Based on your sample data, you can do:

```
UPDATE contracts
    SET year = CONCAT('20', SUBSTRING_INDEX(year, '/', -1))
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you very much. But I still wonder why the REPLACE(year, '%/', '20') did not work…

Comment: @Hynek . . . Because your strings do not have a percent sign in them.  As I explained, `replace()` does not support wildcards.